# На каком языке написать клиент для MySQL?

Tags: mysql, gui, клиент

Доброго времени суток!

Хочу написать программу-клиент для MySQL, которая будет предназначена для управления клиентскими базами данных для небольшого бюро (фио, адрес, номер счёта, номер дела, участники дела, возможность вставки этих данных в libreoffice итп). На каком языке желательно написать программу и графическое оформление? Где можно найти руководство по данной тематике? На данный момент использую для решения задачи libreoffice base, но хотелось бы создать что-то своё.

Comment: На любом языке. зависит от того под какую ОС вы это собираетесь делать, требуется ли переносимость на другие платформы, включая мобильные. Может стоит подумать не сделать ли ее web-сервисом

Comment: Очевидно на языке пользователей этого клиента

Comment: И заложите мультиязычность